# Adding Strings into a Char Array in C

Tags: arrays, c, loops, fgets, strcat

For some reason when I print the array above I get a weird output. When I run this code through the WinSCP terminal it also crashes almost as if there was an endless loop. However, I am mainly looking to fix the print output. Input: Tom (enter) Jerry (enter) (enter to break) Output: .N=?tom
jerry

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int i, counter = 0;
    char nameArr[100] ;
    
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter a name: ") ;
        char word[25] ;
        // Grab input
        fgets (word, sizeof(word), stdin) ;
        
        // Break if no input
        if (strcmp (word, "\n") == 0)
            break ;
        
        // Checks if there is a number in the input
        for (i = 0 ; i < strlen(word) - 1 ; i++)
        {
            int isItADigit = isdigit(word[i]) ;
            if (isItADigit != 0)
            {
                printf("No no, number detected, no bueno!") ;
                return 0 ;
            }
        }
        // Adds word to array
        strcat(nameArr, word) ;
        // Future Usage
        counter ++ ;    
    }
    
    if (counter < 2 )
    {
        printf("Name is too short\n") ;
        return 0 ;
    }
    else if (counter > 4)
    {
        printf("Name is too long\n") ;
        return 0 ;
    }
    
    //printArray(nameArr) ;
    printf("%s", nameArr) ;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to end a string with '\0'. Or the programm does not know where the string ends.

Answer (score 2):

The array `char nameArr[100]` is not initialized, hence it contains garbage. It could be for example that this garbage is: `nameArr[0] = '.'` `nameArr[1] = 'N'` `nameArr[2] = ':'` ...

So, you should write: `char nameArr[100] = {0};` to initialize it to 0's, or make it static `static char nameArr[100];` which will also initialize it to 0's.

Answer (score 1):

The [`strcat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) function requires that the destination array already is a proper null-terminated string.

Since you haven't initialize the array `nameArr` its contents is *indeterminate* and the first call to `strcat` will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to initialize the array before you use it:

```
char nameArr[100] = { 0 };  // Initialize to all zeros, which is the string terminator
```

You should also add a check to make sure that you don't go out of bounds of the array `nameArr`.

---

On an unrelated note, remember that [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) leaves the newline in the buffer, and you need to remove it unless you want your `nameArr` to contain newlines.

This can be done using the [`strcspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn) function:

```
fgets (word, sizeof(word), stdin) ;
word[strcspn(word, "\n")] = '\0';
```

And lastly you should really check if `fgets` succeeds or not.